# У объектов странный цвет

Tags: unity3d

Как решить проблему с коричневатым цветом на объектах, хотя Material имеет белый цвет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Пересоздал проект, и стало всё как надо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Directional light по умолчанию имеет желтоватый цвет, поменяйте на белый или вообще не используйте свет.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, не помогло, дело в том, что я только создал проект, и сразу такой вот казус.

Comment: Вот только что специально на новом проекте проверил, что написал, все работает. Приложите скриншот настроек объекта `Directional Light`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Приложил к теме.

Comment: Еще раз, `нужно в настройках света исправить желтый цвет на белый`, у вас на скриншоте у света желтый цвет, что и дает желто-коричневый оттенок на объектах.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Теперь серый, хотя должен быть белый! (Скриншот приложен в теме)

Comment: Нет, не должен. Вы используете шейдер, который физически правильно реагирует на источники света, что в свою очередь приводит к полутонам от оригинального цвета (белый) к полностью черному (тень) - это и есть серый цвет. Либо используйте `Unlit` шейдер, либо пишите свой, который будет ловить тени, но не будет создавать полутона.

Answer (score 0):

Настройки света посмотрите. Ambient light по умолчанию не белый. Плюс, покрутите там интенсивность света.

Ну или Unlit/Texture shader на материл повесьте.

Comment: Пробовал, но не помогло

Comment: Нужно запечь рефлекшин пробы, через окно настроек освещения, само освещение запекать не нужно.